# force angular to use _ngcontent-c8 instead of _ngcontent-c18

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When page is loaded angular generate this html

```
<ng-component _nghost-c18>
    <div _ngcontent-c18 style="margin-top:5px">
       ...
    </div>
</ng-component>
```

which on ui is represented slightly messy, some controls are not in line with other, padding, etc.

When I hit refresh button html is now generated like this (it uses _nghost-c8 and _ngcontent-c8 instead of 18?)
This refreshed page looking exactly how I want it.

```
<ng-component _nghost-c8>
    <div _ngcontent-c8 style="margin-top:5px">
       ...
    </div>
</ng-component>
```

How can I force to put this second solution into place instead of first one?

Answer (score 0):

You must not rely on attribute names generated by AngularJS to build your UI because you will never be confident that they will not change in the future...

Moreover, I don't think you can force them to be equal to something: only AngularJS compiler can decide of it.